# No se muestran los botones o elementos en android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Estoy comenzando a crear una aplicación en Android Studio y no consigo que se muestren los botones o elementos en la pre-visualización de imagen.

Adjunto capturas y código actual.

CÓDIGO xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnagregar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/add"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvlista"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como mencionaba anteriormente, no se muestra nada en la vista previa de la derecha.

Espero me puedan ayudar, quedo atento a sus comentarios.

INFORMACIÓN TÉCNICA:

- EQUIPO Nexus 5
- API 28
- Android Studio Version 3.1.4

Comment: una pregunta , cuando creaste el botón y el ListView lo hiciste desde el código o desde la pestaña de design? Y ya lo has ejecutado en el emulador o en tú propio dispositivo? También por experiencia te digo que el entorno de Android Studio suele fallar y no es culpa tuya , puedes intentar reiniciar el entorno y si eso no funciona , en la pestaña de "build" seleccionas la opción rebuild project , lo cual regenera algunos archivos que quizás estén provocando el problema , espero que puedas solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue la siguiente:

Cambie la versión de la api 28 a la api 26

y configure el archivo **build.gradle(module app)** dejando esta linea de la siguiente forma:

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
```

luego di click en sincronizar en una pestaña que apareció.
y listo.

Answer (score -1):

a mi me funcionaba : 
1.-Cambiado el dispositivo en el cual estas haciendo la pre-visualizacion
2.- Trata de cambiar la vista a "blueprint" algo asi no recuerdo eso hace que refresque un poco la pre-visualizacion
3.-O la API tambien intenta cambiarla por una inferior